# How change .dict behavior in Pydantic for including an extra deep field

Tags: python, pydantic

I have the two followings Class

```py
class Library(BaseModel):
    package: str

class JobTaskSettings(TaskKey):
    description: Optional[str]
    depends_on: Optional[List[TaskKey]]
    on_cluster_id: str = Field(..., alias="existing_cluster_id")
    libraries: List[Library]
```

when I call `.dict` [Doc](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict)  on `JobTaskSettings`, I would like to have the following result

```json
{
  "libraries": [
    {
      "pypi": {
        "package": "requests"
      }
    },
    {
      "pypi": {
        "package": "bs4"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Where to each Library Model is wrapped around another json Object with the "pypi" key.
Is this possible?

Comment: You mention `.dict()` but you also mention something about "another json Object". If you need a JSON str you can use `.json()`. If you use `.json()` you can customize the output with a [JSON encoder](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#json_encoders).

Comment: You can override the dict method and  customize it for your self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is only add one more class and modifi Library class:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List


class Package(BaseModel):
    package: str


class Library(BaseModel):
    pypi: Package


class JobTaskSettings(BaseModel):
    libraries: List[Library]


package_1 = Package(package="requests")
package_2 = Package(package="bs4")
libraries = [Library(pypi=package_1), Library(pypi=package_2)]

my_instance = JobTaskSettings(libraries=libraries)
```

and the output:

```
>>> my_instance.json()
{
    "libraries": [
        {
            "pypi": {
                "package": "requests"
            }
        },
        {
            "pypi": {
                "package": "bs4"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is more safe than changing .dict() or .json() bechaviour

Comment: That's how I ended up to write my code at the end :)